# Sum values based on cells with an indent

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a certain layout like this:

```
0
 0
  0  5
  1  6
 1
  0  7
  1  8
1
 0
  0  9
  1  10
 1
  0  11
  1  12
```

Above is a list with combinations from `000, 001, 010, 011 to 111`. The combinations all have a certain value, from 5 to 12.
(The enters are new rows, the spaces are indentlevels of cells, the `5, 6, 7, etc.` are in a new column. The 0's and 1's are all in the same column.)

Now I need to have the sum of all the values in which the first 0/1 is 1, the sum of all the values in which the second 0/1 is 1, and the same for the last value. The results in this case must be: `42, 38 and 36`

I can't find out how to programm this properly. I was hoping for something like this:

```
While not Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(j, 1).indentlevel(2).Value = 0
    sum = sum + cells(j,2)
    j = j + 1
Wend
```

But obviously this doesn't work. I can't program this all out without loops, because the codes can be up to 5 didgets (ex. 01101)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using a for loop? Also I think you are using the [`IndentLevel` syntax incorrectly.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840976.aspx)

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1")
    set rng = Range(.cells(1,1), .cells(3,10)) ' Change this to match your range
End With

For each c in rng
    If c.IndentLevel = 2 Then
        sum = sum + c
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: This is not going to work. Like i said, the ones and zeros are in one column. The combination value is in another column, just in some of the rows. The combination value is not the sum of the ones and zeros.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't need VBA. The real problem is an inappropriate data format. Update your convention such that each indentation level is moved to a separate column. You'll then be able to proceed with simple Excel formulas.

Comment: Problem is that I wasn't able to change this layout. I figured out how to solve the problem in code.